# Can Haskell display an object of polymorphic type ?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

In the book of *The Haskell Road to Logic, Math, and Programming* by Doets, at page 152, it is given that

[image]

However, when I type `[]` into ghc, I get `[]` and

```
$> :t []
[] :: [a]
```

**so Haskell does display a polymorphic data type, so am I missing something in here, or does the book ?**

Maybe it is something that is added later into the Haskell; the book is written in 2004.

Comment: No, it does not displays the *object*, it displays the *expression*. If you for example would query `:t head [1]`, it will *not* write `1 :: Num a => a`, but `head [1] :: Num a => a`. So it basically copies the expression you have written.

Comment: Furthermore ghci does some type defaulting which is *not* done by ghc.

Comment: *"Haskell"* is the language; *it* doesn't "display" anything, GHCi does. The book uses *Hugs* though. When I type `[]` into the WinHugs prompt, I get *exactly* the same error as the one shown on the page you've copied. but `tail [[[1]],[],[[]]]` or `tail [[[()]],[],[[]]]` etc., works.

Comment: @WillNess Sorry for the inappropriate terminology; I know how annoying it is from math.SE when some nonmathematician tries to ask a question.

Comment: the only problem is if it impedes *your* understanding. Here, it'd make you ask, what implementation is used by the book?

Comment: @WillNess Totally agree, thanks for point out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the result of defaulting (the process of turning a class-polymorphic expression into a monomorphic one if it only needs to be used at a single type) plus [ghci's extended default rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#extension-ExtendedDefaultRules). Your book may have a section on defaulting, though of course ghci's extra defaulting rules will not be described there. With extended defaulting, the polymorphic type `Show a => [a]` is defaulted to the monomorphic type `[()]` before printing. You can reproduce the book's error (well, a similar one, anyway) by disabling extended defaulting:

```
> :set -XNoExtendedDefaultRules
> []
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 11 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```